# How to calculate translate while zooming in WPF/Surface

Tags: wpf, math, touch, pixelsense

I'm doing a surface app where I need to scale my scene (zoom) while the user scales with their fingers (i.e pinching)

Currently I have it working ok, but the issue is that I need to zoom in on the center point between the users fingers.

I have the point, but the maths behind the translation is hard to grasp.

When I apply a `ScaleTransform` to my Canvas scene, it zooms in on the top left of the canvas, i need it to zoom in on the center point of my pinch gesture (which, again, I do have).

How would the maths for the translation work to keep the zoom to appear to zoom in on the center point of the gesture?

**Edit:**

This is basically what I have:

```
void Affine2DManipulationDelta(object sender, Affine2DOperationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    //apply zoom and translate
    if (e.ScaleDelta != 1)
        ApplyZoom(e);
    else if (e.Delta.Length != 0)
        ApplyTranslation(e);
}

private void ApplyZoom(Affine2DOperationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    //scale
    var newScale = _zoomTransform.ScaleX * e.ScaleDelta;
    newScale = GetCappedZoomLevel(newScale);

    _zoomTransform.ScaleX = newScale;
    _zoomTransform.ScaleY = newScale;
}

private void ApplyTranslation(Affine2DOperationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    var xDiff = e.ManipulationOrigin.X - _screenStartPoint.X;
    var yDiff = e.ManipulationOrigin.Y - _screenStartPoint.Y;

    var translateX = xDiff + _startOffset.X;
    var translateY = yDiff + _startOffset.Y;

    //bounds testing to limit translation
    var rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, ZoomCanvas.RenderSize.Width, ZoomCanvas.RenderSize.Height);
    Rect bounds = ZoomCanvas.TransformToAncestor(MainViewportCanvas).TransformBounds(rect);

    if (CanTranslateX(translateX, bounds))
        _translateTransform.X = translateX;

    if (CanTranslateY(translateY, bounds))
        _translateTransform.Y = translateY;
}
```

Pretty basic really, but it works to a point...

_zoomTransform is a `ScaleTransform`, and _translateTransform is a `TranslateTransform`

MainViewport is a canvas that contains ZoomCanvas which is the canvas that I apply the transforms to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my implementation that ended up working just fine

```
private void ApplyZoom(Affine2DOperationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        //scale
        var newScale = _zoomTransform.ScaleX * e.ScaleDelta;
        newScale = GetCappedZoomLevel(newScale);
        var pinchPoint = e.ManipulationOrigin;
        DoZoom(newScale, _transformGroup.Inverse.Transform(pinchPoint), pinchPoint);
    }

    private void DoZoom(double newScale, Point pinchPosition, Point physicalPosition)
    {
        _translateTransform.X = -1 * (pinchPosition.X * newScale - physicalPosition.X);
        _translateTransform.Y = -1 * (pinchPosition.Y * newScale - physicalPosition.Y);
        _zoomTransform.ScaleX = newScale;
        _zoomTransform.ScaleY = newScale;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do exactly this myself. Basically, a Surface control that can host arbitrary content and allow the user to pan and zoom (using gestures). The handler for my maniplation processor's `Affine2DManipulationDelta` is shown below. Hopefully it's fairly self-explanatory and gets you where you need to be.

```
private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, Affine2DOperationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Assert(_scrollViewer != null);

    if (CanScale && _scrollViewer != null && e.ScaleDelta != 1)
    {
        var scrollViewerContent = _scrollViewer.Content as UIElement;

        //can't do anything if the content isn't present and isn't a UIElement
        if (scrollViewerContent != null)
        {
            var newScale = Scale * e.ScaleDelta;

            newScale = Math.Max(MinScale, newScale);
            newScale = Math.Min(MaxScale, newScale);

            var origin = e.ManipulationOrigin;
            var pointInContent = _scrollViewer.TranslatePoint(origin, scrollViewerContent);

            var deltaScale = newScale - Scale;
            //width and height changes across the whole image
            var deltaWidth = deltaScale * _scrollViewer.ExtentWidth;
            var deltaHeight = deltaScale * _scrollViewer.ExtentHeight;
            //width and height changes relative to the point in the scroll viewer's content
            deltaWidth = (pointInContent.X / _scrollViewer.ExtentWidth) * deltaWidth;
            deltaHeight = (pointInContent.Y / _scrollViewer.ExtentHeight) * deltaHeight;

            _offset = Vector.Add(_offset, new Vector(deltaWidth, deltaHeight));
            var centerPoint = new Point(origin.X + deltaWidth, origin.Y + deltaHeight);
            centerPoint.Offset(_offset.X, _offset.Y);

            Scale = newScale;

            HorizontalOffset = _scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + deltaWidth;
            VerticalOffset = _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + deltaHeight;
        }
    }
    else if (CanPan && e.Delta.Length != 0)
    {
        var newHorizontalOffset = _scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + (e.Delta.X * -1);
        var newVerticalOffset = _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + (e.Delta.Y * -1);
        newHorizontalOffset = Math.Max(0, newHorizontalOffset);
        newVerticalOffset = Math.Max(0, newVerticalOffset);
        HorizontalOffset = newHorizontalOffset;
        VerticalOffset = newVerticalOffset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a few questions, is `Scale`, `CanPan` and `CanScale` just custom properties? Or have you extended a `ScrollViewer`? Would using scrollviewer be easier that using X and Y translations?